# representing a matrix with column/row labels

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

[image]

I would like to create a 2d Array with Java, or a Matrix with a int numbers.

I've already did that..but I still don't know how to assign labels to the rows/columns.

I would like to be able to access any number inside the matrix based on the row/columns

This is my java code

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
    int[][] data = {{78, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 54, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 12, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 74, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 11}};
    String json = gson.toJson(data);

    // Convert JSON string into multidimensional array of int.
    int[][] dataHeatMap = gson.fromJson(json, int[][].class);
    for (int[] i : dataHeatMap) {
        for (int j : i) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return json;
```

Comment: what do you mean label? for example, you would want to acces the data in [b][h] form instead of [1][2]?

Comment: indeed  would like to be able to access any number inside the matrix based on the row/columns

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use numbers instead of letters?

Comment: hey Kepotx, yes because these labels are stored in databases and are needed to retrieve the values. I could still map them..but if there is a way to use labels directly would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ENUM` types which does represend the special index of your 2dim Array. Give them a field called `value`/`name`/... and create them with the index of them in the array. Afterwards you can easy call them with getting their letter-value which does represent the array index.

It´s very readable and `ENUM.<VALUE>` does not represent an `INT` value. So this is the way how you can do it.

```
public enum ROW {
        A(0), B(1), C(2), D(3), E(4);

        private final int value;
        ROW(int value) { this.value = value; }
        public int getValue() { return value; }
    }

    public enum COL {
        F(0), G(1), H(2), I(3), J(4);

        private final int value;
        COL(int value) { this.value = value; }
        public int getValue() { return value; }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        int[][] matrix = {{78, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 54, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 12, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 74, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 11}};
        System.out.println("Value: " + matrix[ROW.A.getValue()][COL.F.getValue()]);
    }
```

---

I would prefer the way above because you see what directly happens and can assign any value you want. But you just can use ENUM.ordinal(), too.
Then `data[ROW.a.ordinal()][...]` will return 0 for ROW because it´s listed first. b will return 1,... It just depends on the way they are listed/created on the `ENUM`.

Comment: no need for the int value.  every enum has an implicit ordinal int value

Comment: your answer doesn't add any new information to the one I provided. it is a repeat of my answer

Comment: @SharonBenAsher It shows clearly a difference between those two kind of solutions and delivers description/examples. And the developing buisness backends a few years I realy know that all POs/Devs want it the first way. It´s more readable, clearly understandable without documentation and scaleable/customizeable for 100%.

Comment: A Java Developer should know how `enum` works and what are the capabilities of this language construct.  to add a custom ordinal value to an enum is simply redundant and raises a question why is it needed instead of the language feature.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher but what if you want to call them like "A" or 100 200 instead of 0, 1,..? With a new own field it´s easy to get this goal. It´s often used and not much to understand/more work to do it this way.For me it´s not important - both are working.

Comment: in the case where the implicit ordinal is not sufficient, then you should explicitly associate an int value to an enum.  that is why seeing an int value means to me that there was a requirement for an exception from the jdk provided ordinal. if there was no such requirement it is confusing: "why did the dev override the implicit ordinal?"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enum`s:

```
public enum ROW {a, b, c, d, e}
public enum COL {f, g, h, i, j}

data[ROW.a.ordinal()][COL.f.ordinal()] = 3;
```

Comment: Your enum types can´t represent an `int` which is needed to set a index. the enum need to get a filed representnig the index. a=0, b=1,..

Comment: fixed. every enum has an oridinal number

Comment: I know but I prefer a better readable and customized way of it. But you´re right. +

Comment: well I don't .  Java is already too verbose.  verbose != readable